# How to import text data into sqlite?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I am just beginner in iOS development.

I want to import three columns of text data into sqlite database.
Is there any sqlite management tool for mac?

Now i am using Lita management tool, But that's not include import function.

My text data are above 40000 with TAB separate file (TSV).
Can i import that tab separate file into sqlite in terminal?

Please advise me how can i do?

Comment: Check this library for sqlite management on iOS: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search `SQLite Manager` in `FireFox Add-ons` and install it.

It's free.

There is a feature for import text and nice tool for SQLite. :)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Base](http://menial.co.uk/base/), and it does have an import feature.  You can get it through the Mac App Store, [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/base/id402383384?mt=12).